# Unity3d: Get a direction vector parallel to plane

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, vector, raycasting

[image]

I need to send a raycast from my camera which is parallel to the plane (Ground) and in the same direction of its forward vector (Represented by the black color vector)

I cant use world space direction because the global forward vector of the camera points at the same direction no matter how much I rotate it (Since its a VR camera)

I tried to use [Vector3.ProjectOnPlane](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ProjectOnPlane.html), but not sure how it works.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is the ground always parallel to the global XZ plane?

Comment: @Ruzihm yeah!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the ground is always parallel to the XZ plane, that means `Vector3.up` is normal to the ground. So, you can use [`Vector3.ProjectOnPlane`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ProjectOnPlane.html) like this to get the desired ray direction:

```
Vector3 rayDirection = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(cameraTransform.forward, Vector3.up);
```